# Use React Hook in StackOverFlow code snippet

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can use React Hook in stackoverflow code snippet?

```js
const App = (props) => {
  var [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <span>{count}</span>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: [Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: replace `16.6.3` with `16.8.0` at least and it should work

Answer (score 4):

For now this is most simple way to port react to the stackoverflow code snippet.

Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333434/improved-support-for-react-in-the-code-snippet-editor

```js
const App = (props) => {
  var [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <span>{count}</span>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```